# How to unit test a style of a React Component using Jest.js?

Tags: reactjs, jestjs

I'm building unit tests with JestJS [(npm jest-cli)](https://www.npmjs.com/package/jest-cli) and need to validate that a ReactJS element contains the CSS styles that I'm looking for.

I tried to check

```
it('should highlight the selected option in the drop-down list', function() {
    var iconTriangleDown = TestUtils.findRenderedDOMComponentWithClass(dropList, 'icon-triangle-down');

    var iconHeight = window.getComputedStyle(iconTriangleDown.getDOMNode(), null).height;

    expect(iconHeight).notToEqual(''); 
});
```

That results in 
   iconHeight === '' 
instead of a value of pixels.

I wonder if window is being mocked by Jest. Or if window isn't supported.

Comment: Did you ever resolve this?

Comment: Not yet. Tried different approaches but the fact that it is a pseudo selector makes it gnarlier

Comment: Could you post the actual code that you are writing this test for?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could test styles though snapshot tests, but Jest does not support evaluating component styles through assertions—that is to say through `expect`.

In order to do this, you need to combine Jest with [**enzyme**](https://github.com/airbnb/enzyme), [**chai**](https://github.com/chaijs/chai), and [**chai-enzyme**](https://github.com/producthunt/chai-enzyme).

This combination will allow you to write tests like this simple example:

```
it('should render style', () => {
  chai.expect(shallow(
    <div
      style={{
        left: '4rem'
      }}
    />
  )).to.have.style('left', '4rem');
});
```

First, create a setup file and add it to the the `jest.setupFiles` array in package.json. See the [Jest documentation](https://facebook.github.io/jest/docs/configuration.html#setupfiles-array) for an overview of this option.

This is my setup file:

```
// test/setup.js
import React from 'react';
import chai from 'chai';
import chaiEnzyme from 'chai-enzyme';
import { shallow, render, mount } from 'enzyme';

// Add commonly used methods and objects as globals
global.chai = chai;
global.mount = mount;
global.React = React;
global.render = render;
global.shallow = shallow;

chai.use(chaiEnzyme());
```

This is my package.json:

```
{
  "jest": {
    "setupFiles": [
      "./test/setup.js"
    ]
  }
}
```

Now, when necessary, you are able to access the Chai assertions API through `chai.expect` and the Jest assertions API through `expect`.

Comment: There is a new way using `./src/setupTests.js` file with Jest. It basically does what you did, but it's automatic and the only way to make a setup file if you're using something like create-react-app. https://github.com/facebookincubator/create-react-app/issues/545

Answer (score 20):

This is fairly easy using [jest-dom](https://github.com/gnapse/jest-dom#tohavestyle) and [react-testing-library](https://github.com/kentcdodds/react-testing-library).

Tiny example:

**component.js**

```
const Component = () => <div style={{left: '4rem'}}>Left component</div>;
```

**component.test.js**

```
test("left shoud be 4rem", () => {
    const { getByText } = render(<Component />);
    expect(getByText(/left component/i).parentElement).toHaveStyle(`left: 4rem`);
})
```

Answer (score 6):

To anyone finding this thread, Jest Enzyme now has a assert to test Styles: toHaveStyle: https://github.com/blainekasten/enzyme-matchers/blob/master/README.md#tohavestylestylekeystring-stylevalueany

The problem for me was that from seeing the code, is only testing objects and I have many styles which are arrays (I am using React Native BTW) so it was not working for me.

I am doing this method to test for a particular style:

```
const render = wrapper.dive();
expect(render.find("[testID='bannerStamp']").get(0).props.style[0].right).toBe(7);
```